# Confusion about extension of functionals

Tags: functional-analysis

Assume that $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is a bounded set and take a function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ which belongs to $L^2(\Omega)$ but does not belongs to $L^q(\Omega)$ for $q>2$.

Define a bounded linear map $T:L^2(\Omega)\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$\langle T,g\rangle=\int_\Omega fg,\ \forall\ g\in L^2(\Omega)$$

If $1<p<2$ then, Hahn-Banach theorem implies the existence  of $h\in L^{p'}(\Omega)$ ($p'$ is the conjugate of $p$) such that the functional $\overline{T}:L^p(\Omega)\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$\langle \overline{T},g\rangle=\int_\Omega hg,\ \forall\ g\in L^p(\Omega)$$

satisfies $\overline{T}_{|L^2(\Omega)}=T$ (note that $L^2(\Omega)\subset L^p(\Omega)$). Now my confusion is: we must have that $$\int_\Omega fg=\int_\Omega hg,\ \forall\ g\in L^2(\Omega)$$

which implies that $f=g$, but this seem to be a absurd, because in this way $\overline{T}$ would not be a bounded linear functional. Well, where is my flaw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flaw is that for $p < 2$, the functional $T$ is not continuous in the $L^p(\Omega)$ norm. Thus it is not one of the sort the Hahn-Banach theorem says can be extended.

$T\colon L^2(\Omega) \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous in the $L^2(\Omega)$-norm, and you have a continuous inclusion $j_p \colon L^2(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^p(\Omega)$. But $j_p$ is not an embedding, thus $T\circ j_p^{-1}$ is not continuous.

Actually, since $L^2(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^p(\Omega)$ for $p < 2$, Hahn-Banach isn't needed for the extension here, *if* $T$ can be continuously extended to $L^p(\Omega)$, the extension is unique and given by uniform continuity.

Comment: Thank you, now I understood my error.